# .php and .html openable only by "server"

Tags: php, html, authorization

I have an index.php page where I have a menu: this menu is different depends if I am logged or not.
By now, I have create two file html: "logged-menu-html" and "not-logged-menu.html", then in index.php I write in php something like:
*"if (logged) include(logged-menu.html), else include(not-logged-menu.html)"*

The first question (I'm just curius).. Is this way correct for load the proper menu? Or it must be avoid?

Now, 'bout my real question: I want these two file .html be "private", which mean they can't be loaded if not trough index.php!
So far I have just one solution: when I connect to my server (it's from my university) via FileZilla, I have a folder public_html where I have to put the file that I want to be avalaible online.
The solution I've found is to create a sibling folder to public_html: this way I can't use the notation "../privatefile/*.html" (if index.php is in public_html), but the users can't reach that folder.
Is this solution ok? Or it must be avoid? :)

Thank you!

Comment: Any file that is available on your server and that is not guarded by an HTTP-password is always publicly available. You can however edit your `.htaccess` file to block or redirect access to certain files or paths.

Comment: If you don't want a file to be available through the web-server, putting is outside of the web-root like you are doing, is the perfect solution IMO. By the way, you could also have a menu.php file that builds the menu option by option based on the current session (logged-in / not logged-in / user level / etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Apache - version 2.4 (cause that's what I'm currently using)

## Auth

You could set a login before anyone gain access to your page.

Go to Apache folder > bin > htpasswd -  Open htpasswd from a Terminal

If this is the first time you will create a password file:

```
htpasswd -c /dir username
```

Then enter the password for the user.

Else, if you had created a password file before, just remove the `-c` flag.

Then, On your `.htaccess` file, type the following:

```
AuthType Basic #Type of authentication used
AuthName "This is a private area, please Log In!" #Your Login Text

AuthUserFile "C:\Apache24\Password.txt" #In which your password file is stored.
AuthGroupFile /dev/null

require valid-user
```

Or, if you want to do that on `httpd.conf`:

```
<Location "/protected-area"> 
AuthUserFile "C:\Apache24\Password.txt" 
AuthName "This is a private area, please Log In!" 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
AuthType Basic 
Require valid-user 
</Location>
```

Now, if anyone goes to your page, they will be prompted to log in.

## Login

You could set a login page to allow access to valid users.

> This is different from the "Auth", as in this case you will be creating files like "Login.php"

First, set your `DirectoryIndex` to `Login.php`, or whatever filename is set to the login page.

Then, create your login page.

In your `<form>`, set the `action` attribute to:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]); ?>
```

The php in the `<head>` part:

```
<?php
$err = '';

if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

  if ($_POST['username'] == 'user' && $_POST['password'] == '123456') {
    $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'user';

    header('Location: Welcome.php');
  } else {
    $err = 'Wrong username or password';
  }
}
?>
```

In the `welcome.php`:

> To prevent user from accessing "Welcome.php" without logging in:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'] == true) {
  echo "You are logged in!";
} else {
  header("Location: Login.php");
}
?>
```

## Deny Access

> I'm not sure about this ...

```
<Directory  ~ "\.private">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

## Rewrite Rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\\.private/ - [F,L]
```

## Redirect

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.private(/|$)
```